# How to use gomock with sqlc

Tags: go, mocking, gomock, sqlc

I'd like to write unit tests for functions generated by sqlc but I don't understand how to use gomock. I'm new to mocking.

Below I'll describe a bit how sqlc generation works.

So, sqlc generates an interface DBTX:

```
type DBTX interface {
    Exec(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) (pgconn.CommandTag, error)
    Query(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) (pgx.Rows, error)
    QueryRow(context.Context, string, ...interface{}) pgx.Row
}

func New(db DBTX) *Queries {
    return &Queries{db: db}
}

type Queries struct {
    db DBTX
}

func (q *Queries) WithTx(tx pgx.Tx) *Queries {
    return &Queries{
        db: tx,
    }
}
```

And an interface Querier with all functions that talks to db (also generated by sqlc). In my case:

```
type Querier interface {
    CreateCustomer(ctx context.Context, customerID int64) (int64, error)
    CreateExecutor(ctx context.Context, arg CreateExecutorParams) (Executor, error)
    CreateUser(ctx context.Context, arg CreateUserParams) (User, error)
    DeleteUser(ctx context.Context, userID int64) error
    GetUser(ctx context.Context, userID int64) (User, error)
    ListUsers(ctx context.Context) ([]User, error)
}

var _ Querier = (*Queries)(nil)
```

Example of generated function *GetUser*:

```
const getUser = `-- name: GetUser :one
SELECT user_id, email, password FROM "user"
WHERE user_id = $1
`

func (q *Queries) GetUser(ctx context.Context, userID int64) (User, error) {
    row := q.db.QueryRow(ctx, getUser, userID)
    var i User
    err := row.Scan(
        &i.UserID,
        &i.Email,
        &i.Password,
    )
    return i, err
}
```

To use transactions I created an interface *Storage* (which contains Querier and all transaction functions) as described [here](https://dev.to/techschoolguru/a-clean-way-to-implement-database-transaction-in-golang-2ba). It looks like this:

```
type Storage interface {
    Querier
    CreateUserTx(ctx context.Context, arg CreateUserTxParams) (User, error)
}

type SQLStorage struct {
    db *pgxpool.Pool
    *Queries
}

func NewStorage(db *pgxpool.Pool) Storage {
    return &SQLStorage{
        db:      db,
        Queries: New(db),
    }
}
```

So for example I created a function *CreateUserTx* that uses *Storage.db* to make transactions. And now all interactions with database are done through *Storage*.

And the question is how to mock database to test all functions in *Storage*. All mocking examples in web seem aren't that complicated. Could you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: I had the same problem. `execTx` is called but all functions like `q.CreateTransfer` in `func(q *Queries) error` are not captured by gomock, and all important things I want to check are in it. Any solutions now?

Answer (score 0):

You can see a complete and problem-free service [here](https://github.com/FLFreecode/RBAccounts) and compare your problem with the correct service.

**Test Connection**

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    conn, err := sql.Open(dbDriver, dbSource)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("connot connect to db:", err)
    }

    testQueries = New(conn)

    os.Exit(m.Run())
}
```

Be sure to view [my project](https://github.com/FLFreecode/RBAccounts) and your test problems will be solved and you will even get good ideas from it.